# Style inserted text in String.format

Tags: android

We're getting a string from the server.  Something like
 `"Here's some text to do stuff with and %s"`

We're using String.format to insert a value from strings.xml into that `%s`

NOW... **what we want to do is Capitalize, Bold, and Italicize the text we're inserting.**

I've tried doing so with html with no luck ->
`String.format(stringFromServer, Html.fromHtml("\n<b><i>$newString</b></i>"))`

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: remove `\n` it does not work with `Html.fromHtml` instead use <br>

Comment: muchas gracias!

Comment: your welcome :) can I post this as an answer ?

Comment: it only accomplishes 1 of many parts, so I'd say no... unless you can address the bold and italicize parts?

Comment: okay. so for bold and italic you need your whole string as spanned below answer should work. but in android $newString is not supported you need to write in `""` as a java string. I think that android studio can do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it should be other way:

```
Html.fromHtml(String.format("Here's some text to do stuff with and %s", "<b><i>$newString</b></i>"));
```

`fromHtml`will return `Spanned` instance which can be used with `TextView`

Comment: hmmm... let me try that.  give me a few minutes

Comment: that worked! Thank you so much.  Please accept this check as a token of my gratitude :P